# E: Unable to locate Ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: software-center

I have tried re-installing restricted extras but still cannot locate the file. Now, when I run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I am getting this message

```
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I've tried using `sudo killall update-manager` the response is "No process found".

I used janitor to clean my machine yesterday, Could this be the issue here as janitor might have cleaned all my packages?

Comment: Did you unchecked any repositories in software sources?

Comment: see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` and paste your output here.

Comment: How do I paste it?

Comment: @Daniel I did unchecked the repository yet no change, I'm trying to stay away from adobe flash. Still cannot find the package with ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: Of course you’ll get “Process not found” when running `sudo killall update-manager`. You have run **`apt-get`**, not `update-manager`.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Ubuntu Software Center -> edit -> software sources
Check this:

- Main
- universe
- restricted
- multiverse
- canonical partner (optional)
- indepedent

and open terminal and doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you install ubuntu restricted extras it will automatically install flash.
I hope this help and can close your case.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use backquotes when adding commands like  `sudo apt-get
update &&
sudo apt-get
install ubuntu-
restricted-
extras`