# Unable to install any software or packges on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, apt, flash, dpkg

hey i am new on Ubuntu i am trying to install flash plugin , packages and other software etc but finding these errors.

```
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for rabia: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because some other process is installing a program at the same time. Ubuntu is designed so that only one process can use the install sequence at the same time.

If you aren't installing more than one program at the same time then restart the computer and try again.

Comment: thank you for suggestion i did as you said.....but now find these erorr..    rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for rabia: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
rabia@rabia-N150P-N210P:~$

Comment: @user242414 check this answwer, http://askubuntu.com/a/261452/10698